# Atualizar annotations

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, annotation

Eu preciso atualizar as annotations no mapa depois da inserção de valores em CoreData.
eu tenho a primeira vista com o mapa, e um segundo onde eu adicionar os novos valores para novas annotations, mas só quando eu entro na aplicação pela primeira vez é que aparecem as anotações atualizadas.
Eu acho que eu preciso ecarregar o mapa cada vez que entro no primeiro view controller.
Como posso atualizar os valores (annotations)? este é o código para anotações e do mapa:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locManager.delegate = self
        self.locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        latitude = lat.text!
        longitude = long.text!

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

            if (error != nil)
            {
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0
            {
                let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            }
            else
            {
                println("Error with the data.")
            }
        })
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark:CLPlacemark){
        println("display")
        self.locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()



        lat.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: placemark.location.coordinate.latitude);
        long.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: placemark.location.coordinate.longitude);
        latitude = lat.text!
        longitude = long.text!

        var latD:CLLocationDegrees = 0.1
        var longD:CLLocationDegrees = 0.1

        var la:CLLocationDegrees = (latitude as NSString).doubleValue
        var lo:CLLocationDegrees = (longitude as NSString).doubleValue

        var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latD, longD)

        var locat:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(la, lo)
        var locat2:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(la+1, lo+1)
        var reg:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locat, span)
        mapRadar.setRegion(reg, animated: true)

        //Anotações

        var anot = [MKPointAnnotation]()



        var request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Radar")

        let appDelegate:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

        //println(results.count)
        //println(results.objectAtIndex(0))

        if results.count > 0
        {
            for result in results
            {
            var anotacao = MKPointAnnotation()
                let r = result as! Radar
              //  println(r.velocidade)

                locat.latitude = (r.latitude as NSString).doubleValue
                locat.longitude = (r.longitude as NSString).doubleValue

        anotacao.coordinate = locat

        anotacao.title = r.descricao

        anotacao.subtitle = "-_-" //String(_cocoaString: r.velocidade)

                anot += [anotacao]
            }
        }

        self.mapRadar.addAnnotations(anot)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está sendo atualizado somente quando abre porque você está obtendo a localização pelo método `startUpdatingLocation()` e consequentemente seu método de `displayLocationInfo()` no `viewDidLoad()`.

Para chamar toda vez que abre esta tela, você pode obter a localização no `viewDidAppear()`:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Mas pelo que eu entendi do seu código, você pode otimizar e obter a localização somente uma vez pois parece não haver necessidade da localização toda hora e então inserir as anotações a cada abertura da tela, para isso  um segundo método serviria somente para buscar estes dados do banco:

```
func displayAnnotations() {
    mapRadar.removeAnnotations(mapRadar.annotations)

    var anot = [MKPointAnnotation]()

    var request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Radar")

    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    if results.count > 0 {
        for result in results {
            var anotacao = MKPointAnnotation()

            let r = result as! Radar

            anotacao.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((r.latitude as NSString).doubleValue, (r.longitude as NSString).doubleValue)
            anotacao.title = r.descricao
            anotacao.subtitle = "-_-"

            anot += [anotacao]
        }
    }

    mapRadar.addAnnotations(anot)
}
```

Note que eu preciso remover as *annotations* para adicionar as novas, caso contrário ficará uma em cima da outra. E este método você chama no `viewDidAppear()`.

Ainda uma terceira opção, se esta segunda tela for aberta a partir desta tela de mapa, você pode criar um **delegate** para que este método acima possa ser executado somente quando houver necessidade a partir de uma nova inserção no banco.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o meu problema